# transfer content from file to file in react using params

Tags: reactjs, jointjs

I want to transfer the NewDiagramName (text that the user entered into the prompt ) from MyDiagrams.jsx to EditDiagram.jsx .
And to use NewDiagramName in EditDiagram.jsx in handleSave function to save the title as the diagram title here:

```
const response = await diagramService.createDiagram({
      title: NewDiagramName,
      description: "description",
      links,
      cells,
    });
```

React,JSX,JOINTJS library,VSCODE.

```
MyDiagrams.jsx file:
```

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { diagramService } from "../Services/diagram.service";
import plusImg from "../../images/plus.png";
import "../Styles/MyDiagrams.css";

function MyDiagrams() {
  const [myDiagrams, setMyDiagrams] = useState([]);
  const [NewDiagramName, setNewDiagramName] = useState(""); // Use state to store NewDiagramName

  const diagramNamePrompt = useEffect(() => {
    loadDiagrams();
  }, []);

  const loadDiagrams = async () => {
    const diagrams = await diagramService.getAllDiagrams();
    setMyDiagrams(diagrams);
  };
  const handleClick = () => {
    const enteredName = prompt("Enter name to the new diagram:");
    setNewDiagramName(enteredName); // Set the value using useState
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <nav className="navbar">
        <h2 className="title">Your diagrams</h2>
      </nav>
      {myDiagrams.map((diagram) => (
        <Link
          className="mlink"
          key={diagram.id}
          to={"/edit-diagram/" + diagram.id}
        >
          <div>{diagram.title}</div>
        </Link>
      ))}
      <Link to={`/create-diagram/${NewDiagramName}`} onClick={handleClick}>
        <img src={plusImg} alt="Add New" />
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
export default MyDiagrams;
```

EditDiagram.jsx file:

```
import { useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import DiagramMenu from "../Components/DiagramMenu";
import { diagramService } from "../Services/diagram.service";
import * as joint from "jointjs";

// Create a new graph
// const graph = new joint.dia.Graph();

function EditDiagram() {
  const [paper, setPaper] = useState(new joint.dia.Paper());
  const [historyStack, setHistoryStack] = useState([]);
  const paperRef = useRef();
  const graph = useMemo(() => new joint.dia.Graph(), []);

  const params = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadDiagram = async () => {
      if (params.diagramId) {
        const diagramData = await diagramService.getDiagramById(
          params.diagramId
        );
        console.log(diagramData);
        // Update the graph with diagramData
        diagramData && buildDiagram(diagramData);
      }
    };
    console.log(params.diagramId);
    // diagramService.getDiagramById(diagramId)
    // TODO

    loadDiagram();
  }, []);

  const buildDiagram = (diagramData) => {
    const cells = diagramData.cells.map(buildDiagramCell);
    console.log(cells);
    graph.fromJSON({ cells });
  };

  const buildDiagramCell = (cellData) => ({
    id: cellData.id,
    type: "standard.Rectangle",
    position: {
      x: cellData.positionX,
      y: cellData.positionY,
    },
    size: {
      width: cellData.width,
      height: cellData.height,
    },
    attrs: {
      body: {
        stroke: "rgb(74, 72, 72)",
        fill: cellData.color,
        angle: 5,
      },
      label: {
        fill: "rgb(74, 72, 72)",
        text: cellData.content,
      },
    },
  });

  // Create a new paper
  useEffect(() => {
    const paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
      el: paperRef.current,
      model: graph,
      width: 1500,
      height: 3000,
      gridSize: 1,
    });

    paper.on("cell:pointerclick", (cellView, evt, x, y) => {
      console.log("Cell clicked.");
      const selectedCell = cellView.model;
      paper.selectedCell = selectedCell;

      if (linkOn) {
        cellsForLinking.push(selectedCell);
        if (cellsForLinking.length === 2) {
          link(cellsForLinking[0], cellsForLinking[1]);
          cellsForLinking = [];
        }
      }
    });

    paper.on("cell:pointerdblclick", (cellView) => {
      const model = cellView.model;
      Swal.fire({
        title: "Edit Text",
        input: "textarea",
        inputAttributes: {
          rows: 4, // Set the number of rows to allow multi-line input
        },
        inputValue: model.attr("label/text"), // Populate the input field with existing text
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: "Save",
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed && result.value !== null) {
          model.attr("label/text", result.value);
          const textWidth = result.value.length * 7;
          var textheight = result.value.length * 2;
          if (textheight < model.attributes.size.height) {
            textheight = model.attributes.size.height;
          }
          model.resize(textWidth, textheight);
          //model.attributes.size.height
        }
        saveToHistory();
      });
    });

    paper.on("cell:pointerdown", (cellView, evt, x, y) => {
      const toolRemove = $(evt.target).parents(".tool-remove")[0];
      if (toolRemove) {
        if (!confirm("Shall I remove this link?")) {
          cellView.options.interactive = false;
          _.defer(function () {
            cellView.options.interactive = true;
          });
        }
      }
    });

    paper.on("blank:pointerdblclick", () => {
      resetAll(this);

      info.attr("body/visibility", "hidden");
      info.attr("label/visibility", "hidden");

      this.drawBackground({
        color: "orange",
      });
      saveToHistory();
    });

    paper.on("cell:pointerdblclick", (cellView) => {
      var isElement = cellView.model.isElement();
      var message = (isElement ? "Element" : "Link") + " clicked";
      info.attr("label/text", message);

      info.attr("body/visibility", "visible");
      info.attr("label/visibility", "visible");
      saveToHistory();
    });

    paper.setInteractivity({ stopDelegation: false });
    setPaper(paper);

    return () => {
      paper.off("cell:pointerclick");
      paper.off("cell:pointerdblclick");
      paper.off("cell:pointerdown");
      paper.off("blank:pointerdblclick");
      paper.off("cell:pointerdblclick");
      paper.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  const handleSave = async () => {
    const cells = graph.getCells().map((cell) => ({
      positionX: cell.position().x,
      positionY: cell.position().y,
      serialNumber: 66, // TODO
      width: cell.getBBox().width, // TODO
      height: cell.getBBox().height, // TODO
      color: cell.attr.fill, // find the cell color
      content: cell.content,
      startIndex: 1,
      endIndex: 5435,
    }));

    const links = graph.getLinks().map((link) => {
      if (typeof link.id === "string") {
        return {
          content: link.label(0).attrs.text.text, // TODO
          fromCellId: link.source().id,
          toCellId: link.target().id,
        };
      }

      return {
        id: link.id,
        content: link.label(0).attrs.text.text, // TODO
        fromCellId: link.source().id,
        toCellId: link.target().id,
      };
    });

    const response = await diagramService.createDiagram({
      title: "TITLE",
      description: "description",
      links,
      cells,
    });
    console.log("AFTER CREATE");
  };

  /*Function to create a cell*/
  const handleCreateCell = () => {
    const randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1001);
    const randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 651);
    const rect = new joint.shapes.standard.Rectangle();
    rect.position(randomX, randomY);
    rect.resize(150, 40); // width, height
    rect.attr({
      body: {
        fill: "white",
        stroke: "rgb(74, 72, 72)",
        strokeWidth: 2,
      },
      label: {
        text: "",
        fill: "rgb(74, 72, 72)",
      },
    });

    rect.addTo(graph);
    saveToHistory();
  };

  /*Function to save the current graph state to the history stack*/
  const saveToHistory = () => {
    const currentState = JSON.stringify(graph.toJSON());
    setHistoryStack((prev) => [...prev, currentState]);
  };





  return (
    <div>
      <DiagramMenu
        onSave={handleSave}
        onCreate={handleCreateCell}
      />

      <div id="myholder" ref={paperRef}></div>
      <div className="canvas-container">
        <div id="secondmyholder"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default EditDiagram;
```

I tried using params but I did not achieve my desired achievment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I need to carry a text from one file to the other in react using props. And save that text a my diagram name (in my handleSave function). everything there is ready for the save itself the only thing that is left is the text itself I need to enter.